# Timestamp array list covert hours minutes Seconds into setInterval time for each 1 seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

```
Hi everyone facing one issue in my react application where I have array of list timestamp's ex:([1651234567, 1651234568, 1651234569]) which I need to convert in to hours minutes & seconds like Ex:([17:46:7, 17:46:8, 17:46:9]) each seconds timer should increase with help of But in my current scenario this logic is not working.
```

The below code I have defined timestamp state array & also In useEffect I'm calling setInterval time on every 1 second. But below code timer remain constant. Please help on this.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

const ConvertTimer = () => {
    const [timestamp, setTimestamp] = useState([1651234567, 1651234568, 1651234569]);
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      const newTimeLeft = timestamp.map((timestamp) => {
        const date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
        const hours = date.getHours();
        const minutes = date.getMinutes();
        const seconds = date.getSeconds();
        return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
      });
      setTimeLeft(newTimeLeft);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(timer);

    
  }, [timestamp]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Time Left</h1>
      <ul>
        {timeLeft.map((time) => (
          <li key={time}>{time}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you always recompute the same thing so you render the same result.

If I understood what you want to do, you should compute the time left inside your `setInterval`. It means you should assess the difference between the `timestamp` and the current time.

Something like below might work:

```
const ConvertTimer = () => {
    const [timestamp, setTimestamp] = useState([1651234567, 1651234568, 1651234569]);
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      const newTimeLeft = timestamp.map((timestamp) => {
        /* V we compute the time left below */
        const date = new Date((new Date(timestamp * 1000)).getTime() - (new Date()).getTime());
        const hours = date.getHours();
        const minutes = date.getMinutes();
        const seconds = date.getSeconds();
        return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
      });
      setTimeLeft(newTimeLeft);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(timer);

    
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Time Left</h1>
      <ul>
        {timeLeft.map((time) => (
          <li key={time}>{time}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Live demo there: https://codepen.io/friedrith/pen/vYMYmBy

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the best solution is to use [dayjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs) npm package.
They have a lot of built in functions, plugins and internationalization as well.

As an example I can provide you following code, but you definitely can discover their documentation and adapt your code for your needs.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import duration from 'dayjs/plugin/duration'


export default function Timer(){
  dayjs.extend(duration)// you can also play with duration

  const timestamps: number[] = [1651234567, 1651234568, 1651234569]
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState<string[]>()

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      const newTimeLeft = timestamps.map((timestamp) => {
        const now = dayjs()
        const targetTime = dayjs.unix(timestamp)
        const duration = dayjs.duration(targetTime.diff(now))
        return duration.format('HH:mm:ss')
      })
      setTimeLeft(newTimeLeft)
    }, 1000)
    return () => clearInterval(timer)
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
    <div>
      <h1>Time Left</h1>
      <ul>
        {timeLeft?.map((time) => (
          <li key={time}>{time}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

You can find their documentation [here](https://day.js.org/en/)

P.S. be careful and keep this component small. React is an component based framework, each time you setTimeLeft it calls re-rendering of this component.